# Android Images Slide show with video effect

Tags: android, memory, slideshow, surfaceview, viewflipper

I have more than 200 images, which I get from the API. I am using ViewFlipper to show slideshow. It has some fade In, Fade Out animations. It is working fine. My question is, is it good to use ViewFlipper with more than 200 images ? Won't it give memory issue ?

I also tried using SurfaceView, but I am not able to give FadeIn, FadeOut animation.

Or Is there any other way of displaying slideshow efficiently?

Comment: try https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider. i think dis is you want

Comment: Use `ViewPager` instead of `ViewFlipper`. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265154/5744335) for more information.

Comment: @Arshak With the viewpager I cannot get fadeIn fadeout animation.

Comment: Check out these links for fade In & fade out animation for ViewPager : [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26740824/5744335) , [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26154181/5744335) @madhuriHR